# Optimisation in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to R and I have a problem with optimisation.

```
d <- c(0, 9.017, -9.017, 0, 9.017, 0, -8.579, -7.849, 0, 0, -7.849, 
    -9.017, 0, -7.849, -7.849, 0, 0, 0, 8.579, 1.168, 8.579, 8.579, 
    -7.849, 0.729, 8.579, 9.017, 0, -0.438)

x <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)

log.like<-function (sigma){ 
    theta = pnorm(d,mean=0,sd=sigma) 
    logl = sum(log((theta ^ x) * ((1-theta)^(1-x))))
    -logl
}

optim(0,fn=log.like,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=0,upper=1)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 Error in optim(0, fn = log.like, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0, upper = 1) : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

Comment: Isn't this awfully close to `glm(x~d,family=binomial(link="probit"))` ... ?

Comment: I checked, and in fact `g1 <- glm(x~d,family=binomial(link="probit")); 1/coef(g1)` will solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
> log.like(0)
[1] Inf
```

You're using 0 as a starting value but that gives an infinite value for your function.  This is why the function complains.  Choose an actual appropriate starting value and it should work alright.  I don't understand why you're setting an upper limit of 1 for the parameter though.  You might want to increase that as well.

Comment: the best estimate is about 5.8 as it turns out, so increasing the upper parameter limit would be a good idea (unless there's some *a priori* reason to set the bounds to [0,1]) [I've done a bit more on this, will post it if I get a chance].